# Get data from html form to ruby in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Get data from html form to ruby in Ruby on Rails

I have some html like this

```
<html>
<h1>Text to PDF</h1>
<textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="5">
Enter your Text here...
</textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to give the value of the text into the controller for this page/view.
How do I do this with rails?

I am new to rails, what is the mechanism for this? I don't need to write to the database just want to hand it to the controller. If there is a good tutorial for this sort of thing that would be great, I am not convince I am approaching this correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your controller-

```
  def parse_comments
    comments_from_form = params['myform']['comments']
    #do your stuff with comments_from_form here
  end
```

In your view-

```
<h1>Text to PDF </h1>
<%= form_tag :action => 'parse_comments' do %>
    <%= text_area :myform, :comments, :cols => '40', :rows => '5' %>
    <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

(edit: added = to form_tag opening, without it code won't work)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `params['comments']` in your controller to get the value.